# get data from List of List of List

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have list of supermarket than contains list of ailes that contains list of specificAiles that contains list of products.

The idea is to get the product that have the nearest date of expiration.

I need to use java 8 streams to do so

Help please

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `flatMap` to flatten the lists:

```
list.stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    ...
```

where `...` is where you find the product in the flattened list with the "nearest expiration".

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) for `flatMap` says:

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element.